# Getting an error as "Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection" in ZK Framework

Tags: java, tomcat8, zk, zul

My code is below :

**home.zul**

```
<?page title="Home" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<window title="Home" border="normal" maximizable="true" height="488px" 
apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.company.login.HomePage')">

 <borderlayout>

    <north height="80px">
        <hlayout>
            <div>
                <a image="/Image/books.png" id="image" onClick="@command('getImage')"/>
            </div>
            <space  width="600px"/>
                <menubar id="menubar" width="100%"  autodrop="true">
                    <menuitem label="Home" />
                    <menu label="Library" >
                        <menupopup>
                            <menu label="JAVA">
                                <menupopup>
                                <menuitem label="Method Overloading" />
                                <menuitem label="Method Overriding" />
                                <menuitem label="Polymorpsim" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                            <menuitem label="C++" />
                            <menuitem label="C#" />
                            <menu label="SELENIUM">
                                <menupopup>
                                <menuitem label="Selenium IDE" />
                                <menuitem label="Object Identification" />
                                <menuitem label="Handling Dynamic Obj" />
                                </menupopup>
                            </menu>
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>
                    <menuitem label="Contact us" />
                </menubar>
         </hlayout>
    </north>

    <west width="170px">
        <vlayout>
            <tree id="tree" >
                <treecols sizable="true">
                    <treecol label="Library" />
                </treecols>

        <treechildren>
            <treeitem>
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="JAVA" />
                </treerow>
                    <treechildren>
                        <treeitem>
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton   id="click1" label="Method Overloading" >
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java");


                                </attribute>

                                 </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>

                        <treeitem>
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton id="click2" label="Method Overriding" >
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java");

                                </attribute>
                                </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>

                        <treeitem>
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton id="click3" label="Polymorpsim">
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java");

                                </attribute>
                                </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>
                    </treechildren>
                </treeitem>


                    <treeitem>
                        <treerow>
                            <treecell label="C++" />
                        </treerow>
                    </treeitem>


                    <treeitem>
                        <treerow>
                            <treecell label="C#" />
                        </treerow>
                    </treeitem>

            <treeitem>
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="SELENIUM" />
                </treerow>

                    <treechildren>
                        <treeitem>
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton id="click4" label="Selenium IDE" >
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp");</attribute>
                                </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>

                        <treeitem >
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton id="click5" label="Object Identification" >
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.testinginterviewquestion.com/p/object-identification-in-selenium.html");</attribute>
                                </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>

                        <treeitem >
                            <treerow>
                                <treecell> <toolbarbutton id="click6" label="Handling Dynamic Obj"  >
                                <attribute name="onClick">iframe.setSrc("http://www.testerlogic.com/handling-dynamic-elements-in-selenium-webdriver/");</attribute>
                                </toolbarbutton>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>
                    </treechildren>
                </treeitem>
            </treechildren>
        </tree>
    </vlayout>
</west>


    <south height="30px">

    </south>

    <center>
        <vlayout>

        <iframe src="" id="iframe2" scrolling="true" width="50%" height="200px" ></iframe>
        <iframe src="" id="iframe3" scrolling="true" width="50%" height="200px" ></iframe>
        <iframe src="" id="iframe4" scrolling="true" width="50%" height="200px" ></iframe>
        <iframe src="" id="iframe" scrolling="true" width="100%" height="750px" ></iframe>  





        </vlayout>

    </center>

     </borderlayout>

  </window>
  </zk>
```

**HomePage.Java**

```
package com.company.login;



 import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
 import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Execution;
 import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;
 import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Listen;

  public class HomePage {




   @Command
    public void getImage(){


        Executions.sendRedirect("/home.zul");

 }

@Listen("onClick = #click1")


public void showModal() {

    Execution execution = Executions.getCurrent();
    execution.getParameter("myValue");


    }

  }
```

While running the above code I am getting my homepage however when I am trying to click on any link I am getting an error message stating : "**Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection** "

Please find the below error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zkex.rt.Runtime.sendError(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zkex.rt.Runtime.sendError(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zkex.rt.Runtime.init(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zkex.init.DesktopInit$RTInfoService.service(Unknown Source)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.service(DesktopImpl.java:750)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1317)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:606)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:482)
at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:490)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know how to proceed further as I am using all the latest jars.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: this means that at runtime, the class is not present. The class is normally in the JDK...

Comment: @chillworld so I have to re-install the jdk file again or I have to re-install the tomcat server.

Comment: there is at least something wrong with the tomcat server, I'm not a server expert but I know mine Java Exception faults. such fault can come from a dependency set to provided, but as it's from the JDK this will not be in your application.  I think it should run perfect if you test it under jetty.  I think someone else could provide you better help with the tomcat problem.

Comment: me too, i got same problem. have you tell me how should i do?

Comment: @PhilipusSilaen this is the issue related to jars. You have to be carefull with the jar file which you are using.