# SonarQube won't display System Info

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

When I try to display the system info for my SonarQube 5.6 server I get an exception in the logs on the page. Any idea what could be causing this?

This question ([Getting an error as "Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection" in ZK Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293346/getting-an-error-as-could-not-initialize-class-sun-net-www-protocol-http-httpur)) implies that the jar is missing from the jdk. Is that possible? I'm using  java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64. Has the HttpUrlConnection implementation been changed?

```
2018.04.23 12:12:15 ERROR web[rails] 
Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection):
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
  java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:633)
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:617)
  org.sonar.server.platform.monitoring.ProcessSystemInfoClient.connect(ProcessSystemInfoClient.java:53)
  org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.writeJson(InfoAction.java:81)
  org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.handle(InfoAction.java:66)
  org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:107)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425)
  org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292)
  org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
  rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D01792011778.__file__(app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:34)
  rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D01792011778.__file__(app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
  org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
  org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
  org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE91792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C1792011778.__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
  org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
  rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778.block_0$RUBY$__file__(gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68)
  rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E043451792011778$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
  org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75)
  org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
```

Comment: How did you install SonarQube? I would like to know how looks like your environment and SonarQube configuration (Java container version, configuration files etc.)

Comment: @agabrys A colleague installed SQ, set up some common environment things and then he zipped the combination and I unzipped it then started SQ. The normal stuff works fine, it just seems to be some of the behind the scenes type stuff I'm having problems with. Give me commands to run to get the stuff you are interested in.

Comment: I would like to see your SonarQube configuration files and servlet container (please add also information about version)

Comment: @agabrys I'm running 5.6.6. Both files in the conf directory are unchanged from the distribution.
Here is the content of the plugins directory:
checkstyle-sonar-plugin-3.7.jar  sonar-findbugs-plugin.jar           sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
README.txt                       sonar-java-plugin-4.12.0.11033.jar  sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.7.jar   sonar-javascript-plugin-2.11.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-5.0.jar      sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar
I don't know what you mean by servlet container. How do I get what you want?

Comment: I did a research, but unfortunately I didn't find anything... SonarQube 5.6 is compatible with OpenJDK 8 (see [requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Requirements)), your plugins list looks ok (see [compatibility matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix)) and [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) class has been changed in 04 Mar 2014 - I don't think that it caused the problem.